Curl command for Rest POST API with Map<String, Object>
If we need to call REST API with Map<String, Object> as a request Parameter in curl command, how to pass a Map<String, Object>, i tried like:
@PostMapping("/abc/aa/{type}")
    private final ResponseEntity<Void> invoke(@PathVariable String type,
            @RequestParam(name = "params", required = false) Map<String, Object> params)
    {
    }

Curl command like:
curl -G -X POST --url http://localhost:8585/abc/aa/default_aa.TEST_varchar100_94946640?params='apiTriggered=true;fromPk=7898989898'


but it throws error:
{"success":false,"header":null,"data":null,"messageKey":"error.500","message":"error.500","errors":[],"exceptions":[{"messageData":{},"resource":"Throwable","messageKey":"Throwable","message":"Internal exception was caught and handled by CustomErrorController (see logs for the trace); UID: ad4e6165-7eed-4682-b587-bca6a6b2532e; message: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map': no matching editors or conversion strategy found","stackTrace"
any samples for a REST API with Map as a parameter - and curl command for the same will help me.

I tried passing params like:
curl -G -X POST --url http://localhost:8585/abc/aa/default_aa.TEST_varchar100_94946640?apiTriggered=true&fromPk=7898989898

params(map) is not holding these values, map shows as null.
some people closes question, before closing please mention what extra information is expected.

Probably this would help - Spring MVC - How to get all request params in a map in Spring controller?.

CURL command to send json
curl -X POST  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"key":"value"}'  http://localhost:8000?param1=value1&param2=value2


d - to pass data
H - to pass header
X - for requesting
F - for form data

Replace param1 and Value1 with key and value of query parameters
Replace key & value of json data value
For more info refer
 How to make API request from command line with CURL  
